# JSP - HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Tags: jsp

Below is part of my .jsp.

```
<%User user = (User) (session.getAttribute("user"));%>
<b>Welcome <%= user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName()%></b>
<br/>
```

And I am getting below error:

> HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
>
> Type Exception Report
>
> Message An exception occurred processing [/home.jsp] at line [20]
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>      org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/home.jsp] at line [20]
>
> 17: **This is added information page**
>       18: <%=new Date()%>
>       19: <%User user = (User) (session.getAttribute("user"));%>
>       20: **Welcome <%= user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName()%>**
>       21: 
>       22: 
>       23: Logout
>
> Stacktrace:
>           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:593)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:482)
>           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>           javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>           org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>
> Root Cause
>      java.lang.NullPointerException
>           org.apache.jsp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:139)
>           org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>           javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
>           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>           javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>           org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>
> Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.1

Can someone pls help? Error is on line 20.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException` is thrown because the variable `user` ( = `session.getAttribute("user")`) is null.

You should add `if (user != null) { ...` at least.

Comment: More probably it indicates a prior error where `user` was not getting set in the session on its creation.

Answer (score -1):

Make Sure you have created Session and set variable as same as

```
session.getAttribute("user");
```

Comment: This does not create the session and neither does it set any variable.